# Magento help (PHP)

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.8

I've recently tried to run a Magento extension on 1.8 - The extension isn't compatible with this version. However, I'm trying to work out a fix around the compatibility issues, so if anybody has any input that would be great.

The error itself says:

> Invalid argument supplied for foreach()  in /app/code/community/Anais/Accessories/Block/Adminhtml/Catalog/Product/Edit/Tab/Accessories.php on line 254

The foreach block is:

```
foreach (Mage::registry('current_product')->getAccessoriesProducts() as $product) {
    $products[$product->getId()] = array('position' => $product->getPosition());
}
```

Alternatively, if anybody can recommend an extension for Product Accessories that would be handy.

Comment: what is your requrirement for the extension that we are going to suggest???

Comment: Please read http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx ("Question title") - thank you!

Comment: @PavanKumar The requirements are that it needs to be used for Product Accessories (Work the same way as Related Products, Upsells and Cross sells) but used to show accessories instead.

Comment: Check this http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/top-seller-new-feature-most-viewed-catalog-sale-recently-ordered-all-products-7-in-one-catalog-by-etatvasoft.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've just tested the extension on CE-1.8.1 and it runs smoothly.
Clear the cache and disable compilation and try again.
Also keep in mind that the extension rewrites the `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product` class (the product model).

I know it's not a good approach (not my best work I might say - but I developed this while I was still learning a lot). Check if you have other extensions that rewrite that model.

You can check with a simple php code that looks like this.

```
echo get_class(Mage::getModel('catalog/product'));
```

If what you get printed is `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product` then it must be a cache problem.

If you get `Anais_Accessories_Model_Product` then there is something wrong with the extension indeed.

If you get something else, for example `Namespace_Module_Catalog_Product` then you have an other extension that rewrites the product model.

In order to fix this you need to make the `Anais_Accessories` extension depend on the extension that rewrites the product model.
For this add the following in `app/etc/modules/Anais_Accessories.xml` as a sibling for the `<active>` tag.

```
<depends>
    <Namespace_Module /> <!-- put here the name of the extension that rewrites the product model -->
</depends>
```

Then you need to make the product model in the `Anais_Accessories` extension extend the model you got from the `echo` statement above.

Edit `app/code/community/Anais/Accessories/Model/Product.php` and replace

```
class Anais_Accessories_Model_Product extends Mage_Catalog_Model_Product{
```

with

```
class Anais_Accessories_Model_Product extends Namespace_Module_Catalog_Product{ //make it extend the value you got from the echo statement above.
```

There...this should cover all the cases and you still get to keep and use your other extension that rewrites the product model (if you have one).

**[EDIT]**

A bit off topic, but it's too long to fit in a comment:

For a fast import of product relations I can recommend you this extension: https://github.com/tzyganu/ProductRelationsImport. It works with only the default Magento relations (related, crosssels, upsells) but you can easily add an other type pf relation.  Just edit the method `getAllOptions` from app/code/community/Easylife/Relations/Model/Import/Relation.php and add a new relation like the others.

```
$this->_options[] = array(
    'label' => Mage::helper('easylife_relations')->__('Accessories'),
    'value' => Anais_Accessories_Model_Product_Link::LINK_TYPE_ACCESSORIES,
);
```

But backup your db before trying it. It is still in beta.

Comment: You're a star!
I am using the Simple Configurable Products extension which also rewrites Mage_Catalog_Model_Product - Completely forgot I was using that!

Changing Anais_Accessories to depend on that has done the trick. Thank you very much

Comment: @ChristopherThrower Just to be on the safe side, check if the Simple configurable products extension still behaves as it should.

Comment: Seems to be functioning okay.
As an aside - Does the Product Accessory data come out in the Product Export, I can't see anything on there

Comment: @ChristopherThrower. Nope. Sorry it is not linked to the import/export functionality. You can use it from the UI only (or you can create import/export functionality if you want)

Comment: Not sure how to extend the functionality for that, I'll have a look into it though - I have about 3,000 products that need Accessories adding, so would be much quicker to do that via a CSV file :-)

Comment: @ChristopherThrower. See my edit to the answer for a possible way to import fast the accessories. It was too long to fit in a comment.